# Wordpress Comments - Rich Text

Tags: jquery, comments, html

I've had a question from a client to enable image based stickers in the comment system. I've built a basic jQuery script which will allow the selection of a sticker and add it as markup in the comment textarea;

```
jQuery(".stickers img").click(function(){
   var img = jQuery(this).parent().html();
   var text = jQuery("#respond textarea").val();
   jQuery("#respond textarea").val(text + img);
});
```

While this works just fine upon hitting submit, the user is presented with raw HTML code until this happens.

I did see a plugin called "Rich Text Editor for Comments", but this appears to have been removed for the WP repository.

Does anyone know of a similar plugin, or how the comment textarea could be adapted to use rich text by default?

Comment: May be this will help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22415/use-rich-text-editor-in-comments

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have tried this solution already. For some reason the script does not enqueue, so I tried using CDN, but when initialising, I get a not defined error on tineMCE - the order is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way by using nicEdit [here's the tutorial](http://imperativeideas.com/add-a-wysiwig-comment-editor-to-wordpress).

In order to get this fully functioning, I had to amend my script slightly.

```
jQuery(".stickers img").click(function(){
    var img = jQuery(this).parent().html();
    var text = jQuery("#respond .nicEdit-main").html();
    jQuery("#respond .nicEdit-main").html(text + img);
});
```

I hope this helps someone.